# Why dataframe.columns do not match with columns of printed dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subset a dataframe based on a list of columns name.

Here is an example of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3',  'A3', 'A3', 'A4', 'A4', 'A4'],
     ['ba', 'be', 'bi', 'ba', 'be', 'bi', 'ba', 'be', 'bi', 'ba', 'be', 'bi']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 12), index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], columns=mindex)
print(df)

first         A1                      ...        A4                    
second        ba        be        bi  ...        ba        be        bi
A       0.825002 -0.569523  0.332106  ...  0.035184 -1.015359  0.889204
B       0.633793 -0.213981  0.761387  ... -1.566489 -0.298129 -1.203579
C      -0.732290  0.774084  0.520561  ...  0.458506 -0.216635  0.968948
D      -0.418444 -1.096581  0.334761  ...  0.962183  1.950046 -0.532924
[4 rows x 12 columns]


idx_select = ['A2', 'A3', 'A4']
df2 = df.loc[:, idx_select].copy()
print(df2)

first         A2                      ...        A4                    
second        ba        be        bi  ...        ba        be        bi
A      -0.109265  1.442299 -0.206023  ...  0.035184 -1.015359  0.889204
B       0.742486 -0.529073 -1.814155  ... -1.566489 -0.298129 -1.203579
C      -0.477671 -0.689706 -0.717814  ...  0.458506 -0.216635  0.968948
D      -2.269811  0.060901 -0.977420  ...  0.962183  1.950046 -0.532924
[4 rows x 9 columns]

print(df2.columns.levels[0])

Index(['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], dtype='object', name='first')
```

I expected the final output to match with the columns displayed when printing df2. Why does the columns still contain the original A1 element ?
Adding or removing .copy() does not change anything. I am planning to perform several subsetting like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced), this is part of the indexing behaviour with multiindex. As the dev team defines it, this is a feature not a bug.

You can use `remove_unused_levels()` if you really really want to clean up your index.

From the Doc:

> Defined levels
>
> The MultiIndex keeps all the defined levels of an index, even if they are not actually used. When slicing an index, you may notice this. For example:

```
In [29]: df.columns.levels  # original MultiIndex
Out[29]: FrozenList([['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']])

In [30]: df[['foo','qux']].columns.levels  # sliced
Out[30]: FrozenList([['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']])
```

> This is done to avoid a recomputation of the levels in order to make slicing highly performant. If you want to see only the used levels, you can use the get_level_values() method.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations and suggestion!